# Fall back to default language if translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

in an internationalised Rails (2.3.5) app, I'd like to show a translation from the default locale instead of "translation missing" - there's a ticket for it but it seems it's still pending:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2637-patch-i18n-look-up-a-translation-with-the-default-locale-when-its-missed-with-another-specific-locale

For example (taken from the ticket), with two translation files, en.yml and es.yml:

```
en:

  hello: 'hello'

  hello_world: 'hello world'



es:

  hello_world: 'hola mundo'
```

When I execute this code:

```
I18n.t :hello, :locale => :es
```

Rails returns "hello" instead of a span with "translation missing".

As the ticket is still pending, how could I implement this functionality? I know I could go through and change all my I18n.t calls to have the :default option, but I'd rather not have to go through all the views if I can avoid it! As it's a patch, I suppose I could apply it to the Rails frozen gems, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are using **Rails 2**, provided that you use the latest I18n gem, add this to an initializer:

```
I18n.backend.class.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Fallbacks)
```

Then you can add your fallbacks like this:

```
I18n.fallbacks.map('es' => 'en')
```

Comment: That's solved the problem (I had to install the i18n gem - I thought it was included in Rails but anyway it's working nicely now, thank you very much for your answer!)

Cheers
Dave

Comment: The basic functionality is included in rails, but the gem contains much more, like an activerecord backend for instance, and better interpolations and such. And from Rails 3 I think it completely replaces the internal one.

Comment: Should probably update the chosen answer to the one below, as it is now the correct answer as of today :)

Comment: That's the problem with old answers in an evolving environment. Probably a good idea :)

Answer (score 161):

**Nowdays** there's no need for using separate i18n gem, on plain Rails 3.0.6 and above (5.0 included) installation, `fallbacks` value can be **one of the following**:

```
# application.rb

# rails will fallback to config.i18n.default_locale translation
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# rails will fallback to en, no matter what is set as config.i18n.default_locale
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]

# fallbacks value can also be a hash - a map of fallbacks if you will
# missing translations of es and fr languages will fallback to english
# missing translations in german will fallback to french ('de' => 'fr')
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'es' => 'en', 'fr' => 'en', 'de' => 'fr'}
```

Comment: @AlexeyZakharov Well that depends on the Rails version you are using. The original question was in the context of **Rails 2.3.5** whereas this answer is relevant for **Rails 3.0.6**

Comment: There appears to be some issue on Rails 4.1 series preventing this from working properly (I remember this **worked** in a previous version), the i18n gem page on fallbacks (https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/wiki/Fallbacks) is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest is to add this to your config files (eg. application.rb):

```
 config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

It's very useful for regional locales like en-US, en-CA, etc. because they can fallback automatically to locale en.

As Jimmy points out, you can even alter the fallback mechanism with:

```
I18n.fallbacks.map('es' => 'en')
```