# Supporting different locale regions using Rails i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, globalize2

I'm using the [standard Rails I18n API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) to localise some of our views.  This is working really well, but we now have a few use cases for regional changes to the `en` locale.

The [API guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) mentions that this isn't supported directly, and other plugins should be used.  However, I'm wondering whether there's a simpler way to do this.

I already have `en.yml`, so in theory I could just create `en-AU.yml` and `en-US.yml` which are effectively clones of `en.yml` but with a few regional changes applied.  I could then add additional `English - American` and `English - Australian` options to our configuration which would map to the new region-specific locales and allow users to use a region-specific locale.

The only problem I can think of with this is that it isn't DRY -- I would have duplicate translations for all common English words.  I can't see a way around this.

Are there any other disadvantages to this approach, or should I just bite the bullet and dive into one of the plug-ins such as Globalize2 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [translation inheritance helper plugin](http://github.com/kipcole9/rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper) for this.

Answer (score 6):

The rails-i18n-translation-inheritance-helper is getting a bit old now, so here's my approach for a Rails 3.2 project.

If you keep both en-US and en-AU in the same en.yml file you can use the yml repeated node to have a super en section:

For example:

```yaml
    en: &en
      errors:
        messages:
          expired: "has expired, please request a new one"
          not_found: "not found"

    en-US:
      <<: *en

    en-AU:
      <<: *en
      errors:
        messages:
          not_found: "tis not found"
```

Answer (score 2):

In newer versions of Rails/i18n, they've added a fallback feature. Works similar to the outdated `translation inheritance helper` gem

see this answer for more info: [Fall back to default language if translation missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324398/fall-back-to-default-language-if-translation-missing)