# How to configure i18n to use en locale if translation is missing in specific locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

How to configure i18n to use en locale translation if translation is missing in specific locale?

Currently translation missing message is inserted.

Im using RoR 3.1.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4223806/252799 and older as copy pasted below (dislike that) http://stackoverflow.com/q/2324398/252799 Dupes make SO worse, not better.

Answer (score 14):

Found similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324398/fall-back-to-default-language-if-translation-missing)

Here is the answer:

```
# application.rb

# rails will fallback to config.i18n.default_locale translation
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# rails will fallback to en, no matter what is set as config.i18n.default_locale
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]

# fallbacks value can also be a hash - a map of fallbacks if you will
# missing translations of es and fr languages will fallback to english
# missing translations in german will fallback to french ('de' => 'fr')
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'es' => 'en', 'fr' => 'en', 'de' => 'fr'}
```