# How use default locale if translation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have page that translated to en and ru. 
If user will come to page with other locale, i want that to be used en locale.
Is it passible?

Comment: possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324398/fall-back-to-default-language-if-translation-missing   (see second answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> config.i18n.fallbacks = true
>
> config.i18n.default_locale = "en"

Comment: to complete this answer, it should be added in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper method in which you can do the following:

```
def trans(key)
  I18n.t(key, :default => I18n.t(key, :locale => :en))
end
```