# How to make Rails infer english translations from YAML translation key names automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

Is there a way to enable Rails to infer the english translations from the key names automatically?

Currently I have to explicitly write the translation, because otherwise it would just output `en, devise.confirmations.new.resend_confirmation_instructions` in the view.

What I currently have to write in the `config/locales/en.yml` file:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      new:
        resend_confirmation_instructions: "Resend confirmation instructions."
```

What I would like to have:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      new:
        resend_confirmation_instructions:
```

And the view should just output "Resend confirmation instruction." which is inferred directly from that key.

Comment: There's no way to do that (that I know of) because that exactly counters the point of translations. In production however Rails will display "Resend Confirmation Instructions" if translation is missing

Comment: Ah, will it do that in production? I didn't know that.

Btw, getting the english text from the english translation key isn't exactly a translation. It's just a convenient way to avoid duplicate work when your codebase and translation keys are in english anyway.

Comment: For that you can configure fallback languages. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7886246/488195

Comment: @dgilperez Fallbacks are just for falling back to english translations if other translations doesn't exist. It's not for inferring english translations from the translation keys...

Comment: hey @Magne what approach did you eventually choose for this?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Actually production will output `en, devise.confirmations.new.resend_confirmation_instructions` if the translation is missing, just like development will..

Comment: @dgilperez Haven't really solved it yet. :( Currently I'm explicitly writing the english translations.

Comment: @dgilperez Will try out your exception handler method, to see if it works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

You can always write your own exception handler:

```
#config/initializers/i18n.rb

module I18n
  class MissingTranslationExceptionHandler < ExceptionHandler
    def call(exception, locale, key, options)
      if exception.is_a?(MissingTranslation)
        key.split('.').last.try(:humanize)
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

I18n.exception_handler = I18n::MissingTranslationExceptionHandler.new
```

You can read more [on the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-exception-handlers).