# How to use English text when corresponding language text doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have text like this

#### config/locales/en.yml

```
record_your_voice: 'Record your voice?'
```

When I'm seeing the page in Japanese local config, the text `Record Your Voice` is shown - the capitalized left side of code.

How can I use the text "Record your voice?" when corresponding Japanese text failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886246/2123922)

in your application.rb file, you have the following options :

```
# rails will fallback to config.i18n.default_locale translation 
config.i18n.fallbacks = true

# rails will fallback to en, no matter what is set as config.i18n.default_locale 
config.i18n.fallbacks = [:en]

# fallbacks value can also be a hash - a map of fallbacks if you will
# missing translations of es and fr languages will fallback to english
# missing translations in german will fallback to french ('de' => 'fr')
config.i18n.fallbacks = {'es' => 'en', 'fr' => 'en', 'de' => 'fr'}
```